# How to route all traffic to a single port on google compute engine

Tags: node.js, nginx, dns, ip-address

I'm hosting a node app on the google compute engine. My app is set to listen to the port 8080. I opened up a firewall to allow tcp connections to port 8080. I can connect to my app by entering

```
http://<your-instance-ip>:8080
```

in the google chrome browser, where your-instance-ip is the external ip of the compute engine instance. I bought a domain. **I want to make it so that when you enter my domain, it redirects you to this specific port**. But you can only add the external ip in the A-record of my godaddy domain. How do I route all traffic to that ip, to the specific port 8080? I used nodejs with express. I want to do this using NGINX, could someone point out some tutorials?

Comment: Sounds like you want to run a _reverse proxy_ from port 80 to port 8080. Google's docs should be able to help with that and you'll need to open port 80 on your firewall if it's not already done.

Comment: Do I NEED to run a reverse proxy, is that what EVERYONE has to do? I'm using nodejs, is there a way to listen to every port from 80 to 8080? Where can I find the "Google docs" to help me out?

Comment: I created an SRV record with goDaddy. I set the port to 8080 and the target to ****.com, and an A record to the external IP of my intance, is that all I need to do?

Comment: Essentially, you want `<your instance>:80` to forward to `<your instance>:8080` - so you would need to have something to listen on port 80 and redirect the user (via HTTP Redirect) or run a proxy that looks like it's accepting on port 80 and forwards the requests, and sends responses back (i.e., a proxy). However, the question is, _why_ would you want to do this? Seems like extra complexity and makes URLs look more complex rather than the cleaner `foo.com/bar` it will be `foo.com:8080/bar`. Could you clarify what problem(s) you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I'm not trying to solve problems, I want to be able to type in example.com instead of http://<your-instance-ip>:8080. That's it. Whenever I type in example.com though, it just connects to port 80, is that what you're saying?

Comment: The simplest method is for you to reconfigure your node server to listen on 80 but that would require the node server to run as root and you to learn how to secure it. The ideal software-only method is to run a lightweight reverse proxy (e.g. Apache or Nginx) on yourip:80, run node.js on localhost:8080 and have the proxy forward connections to node. Then open 80 on the external firewall and close 8080. This is how many real-world servers run. You can accept multiple incoming connections simultaneously and even do load balancing in the proxy.

Comment: Could u point out some tutorials on how to run a lightweight reverse proxy? With nodjes...When I try to run the server to listen on 80, I'm getting some sort of error, I'm running my server on the google compute engine. Linux image.

Answer (score 1):

Click on 'default' Network and Edit your "default-allow-http", make sure existing "Allowed protocols and ports" is "tcp:80" and target-tag is "http-server" also add "nodejs" in target-tag. Save your changes. Restart your google console. godaddy will listen the port 80